# partial select doctrine query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to custom select use this code

```
$result = $qb->select('partial user.{id,name}')
                 ->from('User', 'user')
                 ->leftJoin('user.group', 'group')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getResult();
```

> the result of this code in below

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "admin",
    "description": null,
    "create_date": null,
    "modified_date": null,
}
```

why returned field not selected with null value?!

Comment: try with `$qb->select('user.id, user.name')`

Comment: thanks for your reply,but i want to use array in select arguman like this select->('partial user.{array_of_fields}')

Answer (score 7):

Using the DQL "partial" keyword is not enough to get a partial entity as a result.

The DQL hint HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD must be used as well.

```
$query = $qb->select('partial user.{id,name}')
             ->from('User', 'user')
             ->leftJoin('user.group', 'group')
             ->getQuery()
;

$query->setHint(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, 1);

$results = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: This works... just testing and works exactly as scoolnico mentioned.

Comment: Any insight as to why `partial` alone is not enough?

Comment: @WillB.
It might be because doctrine does not allow to load partial object by default 

`Doctrine, by default, does not allow partial objects. That means, any query that only selects partial object data and wants to retrieve the result as objects (i.e. Query#getResult()) will raise an exception telling you that partial objects are dangerous.` --> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/partial-objects.html#when-should-i-force-partial-objects

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE thanks, my comment was rhetorically aimed at the poster to explain their statement as to why they claimed it is the solution.