# Fetching only certain fields with Doctrine ORM entityManager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

At this moment, I do a query to fetch all users from the database with

```
$users = $this->entityManager
    ->getRepository(User::class)
    ->findBy([
        'userName' => $username,
    ]);
```

The problem is that it takes all of the properties that a user has.
I only want certain fields returned or I want to make sure I don't get certain fields. (I don't need the field that lists if an email has been verified for example).

Is it possible to give the query the field names it should get? Is this even possible or will this kind of query always, and only, get the full object?

The other logical option is to make a query like:

```
SELECT (userName, location)
FROM `user`
```

But is the first approach possible? and if so, how?

edit:

What I wanted in the first query is not possible so it appears. sql /dql is needed to solve it.

What I've got working is:

```
 $query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
 $users = $query
     ->select('u.username')
     ->from(User::class, 'u')
     ->where('u.username = :username')
     ->setParameter('username', $username)
     ->getQuery()
     ->execute();
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912814/2270041

Comment: @Matteo I found something like that earlier and used that for now. Only I don't have to use the 'partial' tag. But that's might be something that's in the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom sql for this (or dql in this case, whatever you prefer):

Go to user repository and create a function for retrieve what you need, for example...

```
public function extractCertainFieldsFromUser()
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select("u.username, u.location")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
}
```

Comment: What does the 'u' stand for in the createQueryBuilder('u')?
In the way i use it now I have ->from(User:class, 'u')