# sFetch datas with specified fields as entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

My Symfony 4.3 applications is very heavy on data consumption and i need to do some optimizations. One important step would be to limit the fields i select from my entities as most of them are only used in the backend.

Here is an example function in my repository class:

```
public function getPerson(int $id): ?Person
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Person');

    $qb->addSelect('person.firstName');
    $qb->where('person.id = ' . $id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

And this is the result I get:

**Return value of MyRepository::getPerson() must be an instance of App\Entity\getPerson or null, array returned**

Which makes sense since it's missing properties. But I've been banging my head on this for a while and can't find a way to map my array result to an object. I've read the documentation about the Symfony serializer but it's unclear to me how to work with a PHP array and not a JSON or XML document.

Comment: Using Doctrine partial object will be a solution I guess (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/partial-objects.html). As @Syllz says, it is better to set SQL Query parameter thought `setParameter` method.

Why do you want to return a Person object ? Dealing with an array it's not possible ?

Comment: Hi, i will check it out, the hardcoded parameter is there just for the code example.

Comment: This seems to fix my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912362/partial-select-doctrine-query-builder

If you post the answer i'll accept it.